# 2 div side by side using css - one move

Tags: html, css, move

How can I place two div side by side
One of them is moving continuously up and down
and containing img

I tried this :

```
 <div>
 <div style="margin:30px;width:100px;height:250px;position:relative;float:left;background-color:red;">A</div>
 <div style="margin:30px;width:100px;height:50px;position:relative;float:left;background-color:blue;">B</div>
</div>
```

Can I make the B div move up and down ?

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? Do you need help getting div B to move up and down?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged this question with CSS and not Jquery/Javascript am using CSS keyframes animations. It is [not supported in  IE<=9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#Browser_Compatibility).

```css
div.boxB {
    -webkit-animation: move 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: move 5s linear infinite;
    animation: move 5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    25% {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    50% {
        margin-top: 180px;
    }
    75% {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes move {
    0% {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    25% {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    50% {
        margin-top: 180px;
    }
    75% {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}
@keyframes move {
     0% {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    25% {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    50% {
        margin-top: 180px;
    }
    75% {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div style="margin:30px;width:100px;height:200px;position:relative;float:left;background-color:red;">A</div>
    <div class="boxB" style="margin:30px;width:100px;height:50px;position:relative;float:left;background-color:blue;">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways:

1. add in your style `display:block`
2. float the second div to right `float:right`

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: inline-block and move your B div up and down with top and bottom.

```html
<div>
 <div style="30px 0 0 0;width:100px;height:250px;position:relative;display: inline-block;background-color:red;">A</div>
 <div style="30px 0 0 0;width:100px;height:50px;position:relative;display: inline-block;background-color:blue;top: 90px;">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have it side by side by making the right,bottom and left margins to 0px.

```html
<div>
 <div style="margin:30px 0 0 0;width:100px;height:250px;position:relative;float:left;background-color:red;">A</div>
 <div style="margin:30px 0 0 0;width:100px;height:50px;position:relative;float:left;background-color:blue;">B</div>
</div>
```